# How do you use GAP in batch mode?

Tags: gap-system

I can't seem to figure out how to use the GAP computer algebra system (for example, if I have a python script, I can do `python script.py > /tmp/python_output.csv`) I can't seem to find any info in the GAP documentation [I am sure it is there somewhere])

Comment: Is `gap script.g` what you're looking for, or do you want a shell script like `check-one-order.sh` from the [GAP Carpentries-style lesson](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/discuss/) ?

Answer (score 3):

Using `gap script.g` works fine, but it does not terminate GAP at the end, but rather switches to the REPL at the end. To change that, you can end your script with `QUIT;`. Or, if you use GAP >= 4.11.0, you can add `-c 'QUIT;'` at the end of the command line to achieve the same effect for any script, without modifying it.

In addition, you may want to turn off the banner with `-b` and enable quiet mode with `-q`. Finally, you can use `--quitonbreak` to disable the break loop so that errors terminate instead of resulting in a hang waiting for user input.

In summary:

```
gap --quitonbreak -b -q script.g
```

or if you don't want to end your script with `QUIT;`, use

```
gap --quitonbreak -b -q script.g -c 'QUIT;'
```

If you feel the need to do this a lot, you could wrap this into a little helper shell script `gap-batch` which looks something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
gap --quitonbreak -b -q $* -c 'QUIT;'
```

If you put this into your PATH, then you can just do

```
gap-batch script.g
```

Comment: The example at https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/discuss/ also shows how you can pass an argument to the shell script to substitute it into a call of a GAP function.

Answer (score 1):

I use unix redirection :

```
     gap -q < file.g
```

to run batch file. It works well.